# Accessing n rows from end of a table in SQL

Tags: database

How could we access any number of rows from end of a table in database (let say show last 3 rows) and restriction is that we have no information about table? (we did not know about primary key and anything else)

Comment: There is no such thing as "the end of a table" in a relational database. You need to think of rows in a table like balls in a basket.

Comment: Last 3 rows ordered by what?

Comment: In any order. OR as they are present.

Comment: @user3157709 Please see the first comment by a_horse_with_no_name. There is no natural ordering of rows in a database table, so there must be some column in the table that you would use to put them in an order. "As they are present" doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 0):

It makes no sense to talk about relational database in terms of a natural order. The natural order does not exist, order is only forcefully imposed when you `select` with an `order by` (or with `group by` which implies ordering).

Once you *are* ordering the output, most DBMS product allow you to use clauses such as `limit 1,3` or `fetch first 3 rows` to restrict how many rows are returned.

Now, before you complain about that giving you the *first* three rows, that's the same as the *last* three rows with reverse order. So, you can get the three most recent users with something like:

```
select * from users
order by user_id desc
fetch first 3 rows
```

The `desc` (descending) clause reverses the ordering so that you get the last three instead of the first. Of course, those three will be ordered last to first but there's often other ways to get around that as well, such as with a sub-query:

```
select * from (
    select * from users
    order by user_id desc
    fetch first 3 rows)
order by user_id asc
```